# Extract users and their groups from Okta

Tags: python, okta

How can I extract all users through the Okta API and figure out which groups they belong to by using Python?

Answer (score 1):

You use the List Users API */api/v1/users to get a paginated list of users. 
For each user returned, use the Get User's Groups API */api/v1/users/${userId}/groups to pull an array of Group objects that the user has membership of.